# Camera won't move to new location when animating

Tags: animation, camera

Probably a simple solution. When trying to animate the camera between two keyframes, I'm unable to change its position except from the sliders under object transformations in the dopesheet. For example, when I hit G and drag the camera around, it constantly resets to its position on the previous keyframe.

[Here's a short video to better demonstrate what is happening:](https://youtu.be/5aWKMUoCJTQ)

None of the transformation sliders are locked, and under tool options the origins, locations, and parents tick boxes are unticked.

Thanks in advance

Comment: could you please share your file (share the link it will give you): https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I'm having trouble replicating the problem (that was a fresh .blend file in the video). And the project file I'm having the problem in is quite large. I go through exactly the same steps as I did in the video, and sometimes that problem occurs, and sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: can't you delete everything except the camera in your file, and share it?

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/fb34d8590e5a4d1b9c67e8d621d371a1

Deleting everything also removed the problem somehow, so I removed as much as I could while still keeping the problem intact.

Comment: yes weird, and if you duplicate it then it works fine

Comment: i loaded your file and could not reproduce your problem on 2.91